# How would I use eps() as an error threshold and what is wrong with my code currently

Tags: matlab, if-statement, while-loop, bisection

```
function [xzero] = bisecting(f,x1,x2)
xzero=x1;
while ((f(x1)<0 && f(x2)>0) || (f(x1)>0 && f(x2)<0))
    bisct = (x1+x2)/2;
   if f(bisct)<0
       if f(x1)<0
           bisct=x1;
       else
           bisct=x2;
       end 
   end 

    if f(bisct)>0
       if f(x1)>0
           x1=bisct;

       elseif f(x2) > 0
           x2=bisct;
       end

    end
   if (f(x1) && f(x2))>0
       error('f(x1) and f(x2) were both positive')
   end
end
xzero=x1;
end
```

In this code, how and where should I include the eps function (trying to use it as an error threshold). At the moment my code displays the error message, so can someone explain to me what the problem with my code is

Goal of the program: to find a root between a positive value and a negative value of f(x) (basically in order for it to work one f(x)(f(x1) for example)  has to be positive and the other f(x)(f(x2) for example) has to be negative). The root has to be approximated to the error threshold given by eps. Also to calculate the eps error threshold I'm trying to use the x1 and x2 values but not too sure how to.

Example of error threshold: eps(a)=10^-10 so 10^-8 would be my error threshold

Comment: Several comments: First of all, are you sure about your algorithm? In the first if/else you change bisect, in the second you change x1/x2, as you should. 
Second, eps is usually a very drastic threshold, at that level you will incur rounding error anyway. Is machine precision really what you want?
I don't understand your last line.

Comment: 1. The function bisectnew should work as long as f(x1) and f(x2) have different signs. (In other words, if f(x1) is positive and f(x2) is negative, the function should work, and if f(x1) is negative and f (x2) is positive, the function should also work.) 
2. I want to use the ‘error’ command in Matlab to display an error if f(x1) and f(x2) have the same sign.

Comment: 3. Instead of having an error threshold as an input to bisectnew, I'm using ‘eps’ to choose a error threshold. (There is no specific correct answer for how to do this, but the use of eps should at least involve the inputs x1 and x2. For example, if you’re trying to approximate z and eps(z) = 10^-10, then maybe you would use 10^-8 as your error threshold.)

Comment: Sorry for having such confusing directions and examples in my post (took me a while to write these out with correct wording).

Comment: Ok, first of all, eps is already a thing in Matlab, it is the machine precision of about 2*10^-16, so you might want to use a different name to avoid confusion. (type eps into the console and you will see)
If your algorithm works correctly, x1/x2 should never be on the same side of your root, if they started on different sides. Hence, you could do something like f(x1,x2)=abs(x1-x2). Once they are close enough, use either or their mean as your root. Alternatively take abs(f(bisect)) as your error.  Both should give essentially the same result, except for very steep curves

Comment: Also,I do think your implementation is not entirely correct. Consider the case where f(bisect)<0, so the first if/else, and also f(x1)<0. There you only chance bisect, to be x1, and since then f(bisect)=f(x1)<0, you will not enter the second if/else, and nothing will have changed by the end of the loop. 
You should be able to implement this with only one use of if/else, apart from error catching.